# remove row by comparing more column values (header name with space in between)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Hi I am trying to remove a row if column value is equal to more than one value. The following example shows how to compare one value to delete. For example I want to remove if my column value is "a1" or "b1"
Also my column header name is 'Sky Product' which has space in between and hence i have used this method. Thanks.

```
df = df[df['Sky Product'] != 'a1']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need:

```
df = df[~df["Sky Product"].isin(["a1","b1"])]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
df = df[(df['Sky Product']!= 'a1') & (df['Sky Product']!= 'b1')]
```

Or if you have too many values to separate them as such, you can together do:

```
r=['a1','b1',....]
df[~df['Sky Product'].isin(r)]
```